# Execution of CTE: invalid in the select list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is short version of my CTE. You can see how is look like code:

```
;WITH MyCTE as
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(CustomsValue_T) AS SumCustomsValue,
        SUM(CustomsDuties_T) AS SumCustomsDuties,
        SUM(SpecificDuties_T) AS SumSpecificDuties,
        SUM(CustomsDuties_T+SpecificDuties_T) AS SumTotalCustomsDuties
    FROM 
        [FACT].ImportDuties AS fa
    GROUP BY 
        fa.TenDigits
)
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE
GO
```

So this code works well. But when I try to add one additional variable like `WeightedCustomsRate` I have problem with execution of code. You can see how code is look like

```
;WITH MyCTE as
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(CustomsValue_T) AS SumCustomsValue,
        SUM(CustomsDuties_T) AS SumCustomsDuties,
        SUM(SpecificDuties_T) AS SumSpecificDuties,
        SUM(CustomsDuties_T+SpecificDuties_T) AS SumTotalCustomsDuties
        ((CustomsDuties_T + SpecificDuties_T) / (CustomsValue_T)) * 100 AS WeightedCustomsRate
    FROM 
        [FACT].ImportDuties AS fa
    GROUP BY 
        fa.TenDigits
) 
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE
GO
```

After execution of this code error is

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 277
> Column 'FACT.ImportDuties.CustomsDuties_T' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 277
> Column 'FACT.ImportDuties.SpecificDuties_T' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 277
> Column 'FACT.ImportDuties.CustomsValue_T' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you need to either aggregate the added selection or add it to the group by

Comment: For the expression `((CustomsDuties_T + SpecificDuties_T) / (CustomsValue_T))` in your CTE, none of the columns in this expression are in the `GROUP BY`, nor are they being aggregated. As @HoneyBadger said, the error is *literally* telling you the problem.  Add them to the `GROUP BY` or put the columns/expression in an aggregate.

Comment: P.S. Personal pet hate. `;` is a statement terminator, it goes at the **end** of *all* your statements, not the start (of the ones that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated). It is not a "beggininator", nor is it a `;WITH` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever, we use **Aggregate Function**, the Columns Which are used in the Select Statement must be in **Group By*** Clause

```
;WITH MyCTE as
(
SELECT 
    SUM(CustomsValue_T) AS SumCustomsValue,
    SUM(CustomsDuties_T) AS SumCustomsDuties,
    SUM(SpecificDuties_T) AS SumSpecificDuties,
    SUM(CustomsDuties_T+SpecificDuties_T) AS SumTotalCustomsDuties,
    ((CustomsDuties_T + SpecificDuties_T) / (CustomsValue_T)) * 100 AS WeightedCustomsRate
FROM 
    [FACT].ImportDuties AS fa
GROUP BY 
    fa.TenDigits,CustomsDuties_T,SpecificDuties_T,CustomsValue_T
 ) 
 SELECT *
 FROM MyCTE
 GO
```

OR

```
;WITH MyCTE as
(
SELECT 
    SUM(CustomsValue_T) AS SumCustomsValue,
    SUM(CustomsDuties_T) AS SumCustomsDuties,
    SUM(SpecificDuties_T) AS SumSpecificDuties,
    SUM(CustomsDuties_T+SpecificDuties_T) AS SumTotalCustomsDuties,
    SUM((CustomsDuties_T + SpecificDuties_T) / (CustomsValue_T)) * 100 AS WeightedCustomsRate
FROM 
    [FACT].ImportDuties AS fa
GROUP BY 
    fa.TenDigits
 ) 
 SELECT *
 FROM MyCTE
 GO
```

Comment: This makes the aggregate functions likely somewhat pointless. If you are aggregating `CustomsDuties_T`, `SpecificDuties_T`, and `CustomsValue_T` you likely *don't* want them, in the `GROUP BY` too. It's more likely the need OP needs some kind of aggregation on their expression. Most likely a `SUM`, which they've omitted (as the prior expression *does* have a `SUM`). Of course, if that is the case, I would suggest that the probably is nothing more than typographical.

Comment: *"Whenever, we use Aggregate Function, the Columns Which are used in the Select Statement must be in Group By* Clause"* This also isn't true. Only columns that aren't aggregated and are referenced in the `SELECT` need to be in the `GROUP BY` clause, not any that are used in the `SELECT`. `SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) FROM dbo.MyTable GROUP BY Col1;` is fine; `Col2` does ***not*** need to be in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I had understood, what you are tying to convey, I had modified the code now Plz check - @Larnu

Comment: Thank you @Thiyagu .This lines of codes really work. But now I have new error Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 306 Divide by zero error encountered. I wonder how I can solve and this error?